# When is the proper transform of a subscheme equal to the total transform?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, blow-ups

Say that $X \subset Y \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ are closed subschemes and let $\pi: \tilde{Y} \rightarrow Y$ be the blowup along $X$.

> If $H$ is a hyperplane section of $Y$, under what conditions (on $H$) do we have $\pi^{-1}(H) = \tilde{H}$, where the $\tilde{H}$ is the proper transform of $H$ under $\pi$?

I have a few statements about where this happens, but none are nearly as strong as I would like.
I'm hoping that my equation holds for generic hyperplane sections (i.e. coming from an open subset in an appropriate Grassmannian).  If this is not true, I should instead ask for a counterexample.

*Edit:* as in the title, I would love to know how this works in general, for $H$ replaced by a divisor or just a subscheme, but this generality is not needed for my application.

**Example**: Consider $Y = \mathbb{P}^3$ and let $X$ be the $z$-axis, cut out by $(x,y)$ in $k[x,y,z]$.  Take $H$ to be the $xy$-plane, cut out by $(z)$.  Then the blowup is $$\operatorname{Proj}{k[x,y,z][A,B]/(Ax-By)}.$$
In the open chart $\operatorname{Spec} k[x,y,z][a]/(ax-y)$ where $B\neq0$ (so replace $A$ with $a = A/B$), the inverse image of $H$ is cut out by $$(z) (k[x,y,z][a]/(ax-y))$$
which is still irreducible, and the same thing happens in the chart where $A \neq 0$.  The fiber of the blowup over the origin is a $\mathbb{P}^1$ which is in contained in $\tilde{H}$.  It is the exceptional divisor to the blowup of $H$ at the origin.  To check this, notice that $(x,y,z)$ pulls back to $(x,ax,z)$ in the chart above, so in $\tilde{H}$ this is $(x,ax) = (x)$.

Comment: What is the codimension of $X$ inside $Y$ in your case?

Comment: @DanielLoughran For my situation, the $X,Y$ are basically arbitrary closed embeddings, so the codimension of $X$ in $Y$ is $\geq 1$

Comment: Surely $\pi^{-1}(H) = \tilde{H}$ if and only if $H \cap X$ is empty?

Comment: @DanielLoughran, The example I have in mind is to blow up $\mathcal{A}^3$ along the $z$-axis, and take $H$ to be the $xy$-plane.  Then the total transform is irreducible, so it must be $\tilde{H}$.

Comment: Are you sure the total transform is irreducible in that case?  It seems like there's an extra $\mathbb{P}^1$ sitting above the origin.

Comment: @Phil, There is a $\mathbb{P}^1$ in $\tilde{H}$ which is the exceptional divisor for the blow up of $H$ at the origin.  Are you saying there is another $\mathbb{P}^1$?

Comment: I added a little exposition of this in the question so you can see what I'm thinking.  Hopefully I didn't make some dumb mistake.

Comment: Cool, you're totally right.